# How to get previous path in react router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Using React router 4.  Is there a way to see the previous route in the stack?  I don't want to go there, I just want to know where the user came from.  Thanks

Comment: Would you be open to using middleware/an additional library alongside react router 4?

Comment: Sure, I suppose.  We could use this info in multiple places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use to get prev location.

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.location !== this.props.location) {
     this.setState({ prevPath: this.props.location })
    }
 }
```

Comment: OP explicitly said they don't want to go there, just to know what the route was.

Comment: i'm pretty sure this.props.location is actually just an object though... Also, componentWillReceiveProps will not actually run when you navigate from one route to the next in react-routerdom

Comment: I think this would work, but you'd need to have a hidden tracking component that's always mounted so that it'll know the past locations. Then you can pass data from there into redux or use React context to access from another component

Comment: Sounds good in theory, but honestly seems really extra. You'd think react-router-dom would have an easier implementation for this.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  I think it needs the dummy tracking component mentioned.

Comment: I used this idea in a component that is always mounted.  Using an array, I created a stack and always kept the last 5 locations on the stack.